# Error trying to make batch apex class to update records

Tags: apex

Anyone can help me with this batch, the problem is that I'm not finding the records of the entity `EventRelation` to update the records of the entity `Informe_icex`.

Thanks,

```
global class Actualizar_informe implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.stateful {

 global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
  //where fecha_del_evento__c>=LAST_N_DAYS:1
  return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID,Comentarios_Invitados__c,EventRelationId__c,Estado_Invitado__c,fecha_del_evento__c FROM Informe_icex__c]);
 }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
   // Create a map for the chunk of records passed into method.
   Map<ID, Informe_icex__c> iMap = new Map<ID, Informe_icex__c>((List<Informe_icex__c>)scope);
   System.Debug('iMap Records : ' + iMap); 

   **List<EventRelation> eRList = [SELECT Id,response,Status,RelationId,EventId,RespondedDate FROM EventRelation WHERE Id IN
         :iMap.keySet()];**
         System.Debug('EventRelation Records 1 : ' + eRList);

    List<Informe_icex__c> listToBeUpdated = new List<Informe_icex__c>();      
    for(Informe_icex__c i : iMap.values()){
        System.Debug('EventRelation Records 2 : ' + eRList);
        System.Debug('Informe_Icex Records: ' + i);
        if(!eRList.isEmpty()){
        i.Comentarios_Invitados__c = eRList[0].response;
        i.Estado_Invitado__c = eRList[0].status;
        listToBeUpdated.add(i);

        }
    }
    if(listToBeUpdated.size()>0){
    update listToBeUpdated;

}


}
```

Comment: can you give little background of the data model of your custom object and event relationship?This would help people here to get you proper answer

Comment: Thanks, the custom object has this field, this the relationship  customObject.EventRelationId__c=EventRelation.id

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't look right:

```
 **List<EventRelation> eRList = [SELECT Id,response,Status,RelationId,
                                EventId,RespondedDate FROM EventRelation WHERE Id IN
                                :iMap.keySet()];**
```

Not sure how EventRelation maps to Informe_icex__c, but either the map needs to have keys that map to EventRelation Ids, or the SOQl above needs to be querying a lookup field on Informe_icex__c to match the map's keyset, not its own id?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BritishBoy. The problem is that you are getting a list from the query and populating a hashmap with generated IDS instead of getting the ids from the EventRelation object. You might want to do a combined query on the soql or get only matching records in your query locator which would fix the issue..
Buyan